# Unable to remove OpenJDK from Ubuntu 12.04.01

Tags: java, uninstall

I ran the following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre
```

but

```
java -version
```

still show as OpenJDK installed. Please see image below

[image]

How to remove OpenJDK from Ubuntu 12.04.01?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: sudo apt-get remove openjdk*

Comment: It worked. I cannot except answer earlier than 10 min.